# bamboo: my custom action in xWork not decorated, the page shows without tabs

Tags: bamboo, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am new to Atlasian Bamboo development and have a problem, if you could help me.

I develop a bamboo plugin and I have this xwork:

```html
<xwork key="viewNFTResults" name="View NFT Results">
    <package name="nftResults" extends="buildResultView">
        <action name="viewNFTLogs" class="com.atlassian.sap.nftresults.impl.NFTLogsView">
            <result name="success" type="freemarker">/fragments/view-nft-results-log.ftl</result>
            <result name="error" type="freemarker">/fragments/error.ftl</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</xwork>
```

```html
<web-item key="NFT:\${planKey}-\${buildNumber}" name="chainNFTResults" section="chainResults.subMenu/chainResults"
          weight="80">
    <label key="NFT logs"/>
    <link linkId="NFT:\${planKey}-\${buildNumber}">/build/result/viewNFTLogs.action?buildKey=${planKey}&amp;buildNumber=${buildNumber}</link>
</web-item>
```

In my ftl file I put in head:

```html
<head>
    <meta name="decorator" content="result"/>
    <meta name="tab" content="chainNFTResults"/>
</head>
```

and the NFTLogsView class extends BuildResultsAction.

Now when I click the NFt logs tab when the build is running, the content of this tab is appears and the action performed and the page decorator is ok also, like that:

[image: build running]

But when I refresh the page or when the build is finished, and I am showing the tab (I mean inside the tab), I get this page:

[image: build is finished]

The other tabs disappeared and I git many exceptions in logs, like:

```
BambooActionSupport.getWebSectionsForLocation(String) threw an exception.
```

and...

```
`[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ==> fn.hasPlanPermissionForKey("BUILD", 
stage.planKey)  [in template "lib/chains.ftl" at line 369, column 49]`
```

and...

```
BambooActionSupport.hasPlanPermission(String, String) threw an exception.
```

And many other exceptions. Although the action URL is the same when I click the tab and when refresh the page.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after a week of effort and help from the Atlassian Development team, we have found the cause and a workaround till this gets fixed in Bamboo.

**JIRA:**
[https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-19884]

***Cause:*** Following dependencies are not injected for Xwork action.

*BambooPermissionManager, BambooAuthenticationContext, JiraApplinksService, 
WebInterfaceManager, VcsRepositoryConfigurationService, PlanExecutionManager, TriggerManager, PlanManager*

***Workaround***

Add the following in the class that extends **ViewBuildResult**, spring scanner will find these dependencies and make them visible for plugin class loader when xwork action gets instantiated.

```
@ComponentImport
private BambooPermissionManager bambooPermissionManager;
@ComponentImport
private BambooAuthenticationContext bambooAuthenticationContext;
@ComponentImport
private JiraApplinksService jiraApplinksService;
@ComponentImport
private WebInterfaceManager webInterfaceManager;
@ComponentImport
private VcsRepositoryConfigurationService vcsRepositoryConfigurationService;
@ComponentImport
private PlanExecutionManager planExecutionManager;
@ComponentImport
private TriggerManager triggerManager;
@ComponentImport
private PlanManager planManager;
```

In ***pom.xml*** add the following (this might not be needed for the most recent version of spring scanner)

```
<Import-Package>
 org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
 org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
 com.atlassian.bamboo.applinks.*;resolution:="optional",
 com.atlassian.bamboo.build.*;resolution:="optional",
 com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.*;resolution:="optional",
 com.atlassian.bamboo.plan.trigger.*;resolution:="optional",
 com.atlassian.bamboo.security.*;resolution:="optional",
 com.atlassian.bamboo.user.*;resolution:="optional",
 com.atlassian.bamboo.vcs.configuration.service.*:="optional",
 com.atlassian.plugin.web.*;resolution:="optional",
 *
</Import-Package>
```

Link: Atlassian Forum

https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/problem-with-decorator-in-xwork-the-page-is-displayed-without-tabs-and-lot-of-exceptions-in-the-log/18516/26